# How can I remove a string/number from a list of numbers in Coldfusion?

Tags: string, coldfusion, replace, coldfusion-8

Only stupid problems today... (still running `coldfusion8`)

I'm still messing with my list of strings. Now I need to remove 1 number out of the list...:

```
<cfdump output="e:\dump.txt" label="catch" var="--- drop ---">
<cfdump output="e:\dump.txt" label="catch" var="#ToString(variables.searchString)#">
<cfdump output="e:\dump.txt" label="catch" var="#ToString(variables.updateArticle)#">

<cfset Replace(ToString(variables.searchString), ToString(variables.updateArticle), "")>

<cfdump output="e:\dump.txt" label="catch" var="--- drop ----">
<cfdump output="e:\dump.txt" label="catch" var="#variables.searchString#">
```

My dump shows the following:

```
--- drop ---- 
596925,596864,596871 
596925
---- done ----
596925,596864,596871
```

**Question:**
Any idea, why this is not working? `ToString` already is a desperation attempt...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used coldfusion since cf8 came out but aren't you supposed to do:

```
<cfset variables.searchString = Replace(variables.searchString, variables.updateArticle, "")>
```

Comment: There goes another hour in my life, which I could have spent more useful had I asked on SO immideately :-D   THANK!

Comment: Sounds like you're burnt out. Better take a vacation soon.

Comment: Yeah, that sun on your gravatar looks tempting... ;-)

Comment: hmm, `replace()` does not take care of the delimiter.

Comment: @Henry Is that why you down voted after the OP accepted the answer?

Answer (score 3):

```
var foundAt = listFind(searchString, updateArticle);

if (foundAt)
    searchString = ListDeleteAt(searchString, foundAt);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `replace` function returns a value. You're currently using it as though you were doing a direct output.

```
<cfset fixedText = Replace(ToString(variables.searchString), ToString(variables.updateArticle), "")>
```

Comment: dito as my comment below. I think you are on to something :-)